# Terrain generator in a PyGame game

Tags: python, pygame, performance

In my game, there is a terrain generator subsequently resulting in many instances.

I have implemented this code:

```
for b in blocklist:
    if b.rect.left>=0:
       if b.rect.right<=640:
          screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)
```

It only renders things within the screen (400-500 blocks), but it still runs as if it were rendering all 2000 or so.

Why is it so slow? Does it have anything to do with `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()`? Is there even a difference?

Here is the entire code:

```
#Init stuff
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *
from collections import namedtuple
import time, string
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=500)
f=open('texdir.txt','r')
texdir=f.read()
f.close()
f=open(texdir+"\\splash.txt",'r')
splash=f.read()
splash=splash.replace('(','')
splash=splash.replace(')','')
splash=splash.split(',')
f.close()
splashlen=len(splash)
chc=random.randint(0,int(splashlen))
splash=splash[chc-1]
f=open(texdir+"//backcolor.txt")
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("PiBlocks | By Sam Tubb")
max_gravity = 100
blocksel=texdir+"\\dirt.png"
btype='block'
backimg = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\menu.png").convert()
backimg = pygame.transform.scale(backimg, (640,480))
clsimg = pygame.image.load("clear.bmp").convert()
clsimg = pygame.transform.scale(clsimg, (640,480))
ingame=0
sbtn=pygame.image.load("startbtn.png").convert()
qbtn=pygame.image.load("quitbtn.png").convert()
tbtn=pygame.image.load("texbtn.png").convert()
sbtnrect=sbtn.get_rect()
sbtnrect.x=220
sbtnrect.y=190
qbtnrect=qbtn.get_rect()
qbtnrect.x=220
qbtnrect.y=225
tbtnrect=tbtn.get_rect()
tbtnrect.x=220
tbtnrect.y=260
go=0
gotime=35
select=1
colliding = False
Move = namedtuple('Move', ['up', 'left', 'right'])
player=[]
blocklist=[]
font=pygame.font.Font(None,18)

#set cursor
curs = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\cursor.png").convert()
curs.set_colorkey((0,255,0))

#set backcolor
COLOR=f.read()
f.close()
COLOR=COLOR.replace('(','')
COLOR=COLOR.replace(')','')
COLOR=COLOR.split(',')
c1=COLOR[0]
c2=COLOR[1]
c3=COLOR[2]

#load sounds
place=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place.wav')
place2=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place2.wav')
place3=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place3.wav')

#set sprites and animation frames
psprite = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr.png").convert()
psprite.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
psprite2 = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr2.png").convert()
psprite2.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
psprite3 = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr3.png").convert()
psprite3.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
anim=1
class Block(object):
        def __init__(self,x,y,sprite,btype):
                if blocksel==texdir+"\\woodslab.png":
                       self.btype='slab'
                       self.sprite = pygame.image.load(sprite).convert()
                       self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(top=y+16, left=x)
                else:
                       self.btype='block'
                       self.sprite = pygame.image.load(sprite).convert_alpha()
                       self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)


class Player(object):
    sprite=psprite
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)
        # indicates that we are standing on the ground
        # and thus are "allowed" to jump
        self.on_ground = True
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.jump_speed = 7
        self.move_speed = 3

    def update(self, move, blocks):

        # check if we can jump 
        if move.up and self.on_ground:
            self.yvel -= self.jump_speed

        # simple left/right movement
        if move.left:
                self.xvel = -self.move_speed
        if move.right:
                self.xvel = self.move_speed

        # if in the air, fall down
        if not self.on_ground:
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # but not too fast
            if self.yvel > max_gravity: self.yvel = max_gravity

        # if no left/right movement, x speed is 0, of course
        if not (move.left or move.right):
            self.xvel = 0

        # move horizontal, and check for horizontal collisions
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, blocks)

        # move vertically, and check for vertical collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.on_ground = False;
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, blocks)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, blocks):
        # all blocks that we collide with
        for block in [blocks[i] for i in self.rect.collidelistall(blocks)]:

            # if xvel is > 0, we know our right side bumped 
            # into the left side of a block etc.
            if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = block.rect.right

            # if yvel > 0, we are falling, so if a collision happpens 
            # we know we hit the ground (remember, we seperated checking for
            # horizontal and vertical collision, so if yvel != 0, xvel is 0)
            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                self.on_ground = True
                self.yvel = 0
            # if yvel < 0 and a collision occurs, we bumped our head
            # on a block above us
            if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")
while True:
        for block in blocklist:
                if any(block.rect.colliderect(b.rect) for b in blocklist if b is not block):
                        if b.btype=='slab':
                                blocklist.remove(block)
                        else:
                                blocklist.remove(b)
        if ingame==1:
            screen.fill((int(c1),int(c2),int(c3)))
            mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[K_a]:
                    anim+=1
                    if anim==9:
                            anim=1
            if key[K_d]:
                    anim+=1
                    if anim==9:
                            anim=1
            if key[K_1]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\dirt.png"
                btype='block'
                select=1
            if key[K_2]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\stonetile.png"
                btype='block'
                select=2
            if key[K_3]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\stone.png"
                btype='block'
                select=3
            if key[K_4]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\sand.png"
                btype='block'
                select=4
            if key[K_5]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\woodplank.png"
                btype='block'
                select=5
            if key[K_6]:
                blocksel=texdir+"\\woodslab.png"
                btype='slab'
                select=6
            if key[K_LEFT]:
                try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.left+=32
                except:
                        pass
                try:
                        player.rect.left+=32
                except:
                        pass
            if key[K_RIGHT]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.left-=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.left-=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_UP]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.top+=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.top+=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_DOWN]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.top-=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.top-=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_ESCAPE]:
                execfile('PiBlocks.pyw')
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    exit()
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        if event.button==4:
                                if select<9:
                                        select=select+1
                                else:
                                        select=1
                        elif event.button==5:
                                if select>1:
                                        select=select-1
                                else:
                                        select=9
                        if select==1:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\dirt.png"
                                btype='block'
                        if select==2:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\stonetile.png"
                                btype='block'
                        if select==3:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\stone.png"
                                btype='block'
                        if select==4:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\sand.png"
                                btype='block'
                        if select==5:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\woodplank.png"
                                btype='block'
                        if select==6:
                                blocksel=texdir+"\\woodslab.png"
                                btype='slab'


                if key[K_LSHIFT]:
                    if event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                        if not any(block.rect.collidepoint(mse) for block in blocklist):
                            snd=random.randint(1,3)
                            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                            if go==1:
                                        if snd==1:
                                            place.play()
                                        elif snd==2:
                                            place2.play()
                                        elif snd==3:
                                            place3.play()
                                        blocklist.append(Block(x,y,blocksel,btype))
                if key[K_RSHIFT]:
                    if event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                        to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                        for b in to_remove:
                                if go==1:
                                        blocklist.remove(b)
                else:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                        if event.button == 1:
                            to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                            for b in to_remove:
                                if go==1:
                                        blocklist.remove(b)

                            if not to_remove:
                                snd=random.randint(1,3)
                                x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                                y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                                if go==1:
                                        if snd==1:
                                            place.play()
                                        elif snd==2:
                                            place2.play()
                                        elif snd==3:
                                            place3.play()
                                        blocklist.append(Block(x,y,blocksel,btype))

                        elif event.button == 3:
                            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                            player=Player(x+16,y+16)

            move = Move(key[K_w], key[K_a], key[K_d])

            for b in blocklist:
                    if b.rect.left>=0:
                            if b.rect.right<=640:
                                    screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)

            if player:
                player.update(move, blocklist)
                if anim==1 or anim==2 or anim==3:
                        screen.blit(psprite, player.rect)
                elif anim==4 or anim==5 or anim==6:
                        screen.blit(psprite2, player.rect)
                elif anim==7 or anim==8 or anim==9:
                        screen.blit(psprite3, player.rect)
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            screen.blit(curs,(x,y))
            clock.tick(60)
            x=blocksel.replace(texdir,'')
            x=x.replace('.png','')
            vers=font.render('PiBlocks Alpha 0.6',True,(255,255,255))
            tex=font.render('Selected Texture Pack: '+texdir,True,(255,255,255))
            words=font.render('Selected Block: '+str(x), True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(vers,(1,1))
            screen.blit(tex,(1,12))
            screen.blit(words,(1,25))
            if gotime==0:
                    go=1
            else:
                    gotime-=1
            pygame.display.update()
        elif ingame==0:
                blocklist=[]
                mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                player=[]
                key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                text=font.render(splash, True, (255,255,255))
                if key[K_RETURN]:
                        ingame=1
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            exit()
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                                print event.key
                if sbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                ingame='gen'
                                top=(random.randint(5,8)*32)
                                cen=(top+random.randint(4,6)*32)
                                down=15
                                across=0
                                blklvl=0
                                while across<640:
                                        while down>0:
                                                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                                                if blklvl==top:
                                                        blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\grass.png",'block'))
                                                if blklvl>top:
                                                        if blklvl<cen:
                                                                blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\dirt.png",'block'))
                                                if blklvl>cen-1:
                                                        blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\stone.png",'block'))
                                                down=down-1
                                                blklvl=blklvl+32

                                        if down==0:
                                                if across<1920:
                                                        per=(across/(32/5))
                                                        if per>100:
                                                                per=100
                                                        top=(random.randint(5,8)*32)
                                                        cen=(top+random.randint(4,6)*32)
                                                        down=15 
                                                        blklvl=0
                                                        across=across+32
                                                        down=15
                                                        drawgen=font.render('GENERATION:'+str(per)+'%%', True, (255,255,255))
                                                        screen.blit(drawgen,(1,1))
                                                        pygame.display.flip()
                                        go=0
                                        ingame=1

                if qbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                exit()
                if tbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                ingame='texsel'
                screen.blit(backimg,(0,0))
                screen.blit(text,(364,76))
                screen.blit(sbtn,sbtnrect)
                screen.blit(qbtn,qbtnrect)
                screen.blit(tbtn,tbtnrect)
                pygame.display.flip()
        elif ingame=='texsel':
                 screen.blit(clsimg,(0,0))
                 inp = ask(screen, 'Texture Directory')
                 f=open('texdir.txt','w')
                 f.write(str(inp))
                 f.close()
                 pygame.display.flip()
                 execfile('PiBlocks.pyw')
```

Comment: Just changed the code to make it load each sprite one time, but it still runs quite slow!

Comment: First thoughts: that's a lot of global variables, this should probably be split up into multiple files, and the indentation appears to be inconsistent.

Comment: Do you mean multiple .py files?

Comment: Yes. You may be able to split it up into multiple `.py` files and have them import each-other as modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, a lot of people who would answer this question will not do so because you can't just copy/paste the code and run it. The code depends on a lot of external files, like images and textfiles, and to run your code, you basically have to trial'n'error your way while creating a bunch of placeholder images...

---

I'll try to read your code and comment it step by step.

```
f=open('texdir.txt','r')
texdir=f.read()
f.close()
f=open(texdir+"\\splash.txt",'r')
splash=f.read()
splash=splash.replace('(','')
splash=splash.replace(')','')
splash=splash.split(',')
f.close()
...
f=open(texdir+"//backcolor.txt")
```

Here you read some settings/configurations. Better use the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module. It will make your code more readable and more easily to follow.

---

```
splashlen=len(splash)
chc=random.randint(0,int(splashlen))
splash=splash[chc-1]
```

To select a random element from as list, you can just use `random.choice`.

---

```
f=open(texdir+"//backcolor.txt")
...
blocksel=texdir+"\\dirt.png"
```

Sometimes you use `//` in a path, sometimes `\\`. Better use `os.path.join` to create a path so it will work on different operating systems,

---

```
COLOR=f.read()
f.close()
COLOR=COLOR.replace('(','')
COLOR=COLOR.replace(')','')
COLOR=COLOR.split(',')
c1=COLOR[0]
c2=COLOR[1]
c3=COLOR[2]

...

if ingame==1:
    screen.fill((int(c1),int(c2),int(c3)))
```

Well, that's a whole lot of code to read a simple tuple. Let be point to `ast.literal_eval`, which allows you to savely read a string and convert it into a python structure:

```
line = f.read()
# assuming 'line' is a string representing a tuple, like (120, 120, 200)
back_color = literal_eval(line) # now, back_color is a tuple

...

if ingame==1:
    screen.fill(back_color)
```

---

```
if key[K_1]:
    blocksel=texdir+"\\dirt.png"
    btype='block'
    select=1
if key[K_2]:
    blocksel=texdir+"\\stonetile.png"
    btype='block'
    select=2
```

Here, you have three (maybe four if you count the key) values that are connectet to each other, so you should create a type that represents this:

```
class BlockType(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type, image_path=None, y_offset=0):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        if not image_path:
            image_path = name + '.png'
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.y_offset = y_offset

    def get_rect(self, x, y):
        return self.image.get_rect(top=y+self.y_offset, left=x)


class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, block_type):
        self.block_type = block_type
        self.image = block_type.image
        self.rect = block_type.get_rect(x, y)

    # don't know if we need the information 'block or slab'         
types = [BlockType('dirt', 'block'), 
         BlockType('stonetile', 'block'), 
         BlockType('stone', 'block'),
         BlockType('grass', 'block'),
         BlockType('sand', 'block'),
         BlockType('woodplank', 'block'),
         BlockType('woodslab', 'slab', y_offset=16)]

block_lookup = {t.name: t for t in types}
key_map = dict(zip([K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4, K_5, K_6], types))
```

Also, this will allow to remove *a lot* of code duplication.

---

```
if event.button==4:
        if select < 9:
                select=select+1
        else:
                select=1
elif event.button==5:
        if select>1:
                select=select-1
        else:
                select=9
```

can be simplified to

```
num_of_types = len(types)

if event.button==4:
    select += 1
elif event.button==5:
    select -= 1
select = max(min(select, num_of_types), 0)
```

---

```
if blklvl==top:
        blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\grass.png",'block'))
if blklvl>top:
        if blklvl<cen:
                blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\dirt.png",'block'))
if blklvl>cen-1:
        blocklist.append(Block(across,blklvl,texdir+"\\stone.png",'block'))
```

Notice how you repeat the filenames to each different block type all over again? Let's fix that by creating a factory method that uses our new `block_lookup` dictionary:

```
# this lookup could also be directly in the Block class
def block_factory(name, x, y):
    return Block(x, y, block_lookup[name])

...

if blklvl == top:
    blocklist.append(block_factory(across, blklvl , 'grass'))
if blklvl > top and blklvl<cen:
    blocklist.append(block_factory(across, blklvl , 'dirt'))
if blklvl > cen-1:
    blocklist.append(block_factory(across, blklvl , 'stone'))
```

---

```
vers=font.render('PiBlocks Alpha 0.6',True,(255,255,255))
tex=font.render('Selected Texture Pack: '+texdir,True,(255,255,255))
```

You render the text surface once each frame. Text rendering in pygame is quite slow, so you should cache the text surfaces and reuse them.

---

```
for block in blocklist:
    if any(block.rect.colliderect(b.rect) for b in blocklist if b is not block):
        if b.btype=='slab':
            blocklist.remove(block)
        else:
            blocklist.remove(b)
```

No idea what you try to do here. `b` is declared in the list comprehension above and should not be used outside of it.

---

There's a lot more what could be improved, but we've already eliminated two performance bottlenecks (reloading images from disk every time a new block is created, text rendering), and I'm running out of space and time, so here's the complete code so far:

```
#Init stuff
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *
from collections import namedtuple
import time, string

import ConfigParser
from ast import literal_eval
from functools import partial
import os

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("settings.cfg")
options = partial(config.get, 'Options')

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=500)
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption(options('Caption'))

size = literal_eval(options('ScreenSize'))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
back_color = literal_eval(options('Backcolor'))
splash = random.choice(literal_eval(options('Splash')))

max_gravity = 100

texdir = options('TextureDir')

backimg = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\menu.png").convert()
backimg = pygame.transform.scale(backimg, (640,480))
clsimg = pygame.image.load("clear.bmp").convert()
clsimg = pygame.transform.scale(clsimg, (640,480))
ingame=0
sbtn=pygame.image.load("startbtn.png").convert()
qbtn=pygame.image.load("quitbtn.png").convert()
tbtn=pygame.image.load("texbtn.png").convert()
sbtnrect=sbtn.get_rect()
sbtnrect.x=220
sbtnrect.y=190
qbtnrect=qbtn.get_rect()
qbtnrect.x=220
qbtnrect.y=225
tbtnrect=tbtn.get_rect()
tbtnrect.x=220
tbtnrect.y=260
go=0
gotime=35
select=1
colliding = False
Move = namedtuple('Move', ['up', 'left', 'right'])
player=[]
blocklist=[]
font=pygame.font.Font(None,18)

#set cursor
curs = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\cursor.png").convert()
curs.set_colorkey((0,255,0))

#load sounds
place=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place.wav')
place2=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place2.wav')
place3=pygame.mixer.Sound('sound\\place3.wav')

#set sprites and animation frames
psprite = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr.png").convert()
psprite.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
psprite2 = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr2.png").convert()
psprite2.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
psprite3 = pygame.image.load(texdir+"\\player\\playr3.png").convert()
psprite3.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
anim=1

class BlockType(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type, image_path=None, y_offset=0):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        if not image_path:
            image_path = name + '.png'
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.y_offset = y_offset

    def get_rect(self, x, y):
        return self.image.get_rect(top=y+self.y_offset, left=x)

class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, block_type):
        self.block_type = block_type
        self.image = block_type.image
        self.rect = block_type.get_rect(x, y)

types = [BlockType('dirt', 'block'), 
         BlockType('stonetile', 'block'), 
         BlockType('stone', 'block'),
         BlockType('grass', 'block'),
         BlockType('sand', 'block'),
         BlockType('woodplank', 'block'),
         BlockType('woodslab', 'slab', y_offset=16)]

block_lookup = {t.name: t for t in types}

def block_factory(name, x, y):
    return Block(x, y, block_lookup[name])

num_of_types = len(types)

key_map = dict(zip([K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4, K_5, K_6], types))

selected_block_type = next(t for t in types if t.name == options('DefaultBlock'))
selected_block_index = types.index(selected_block_type) 

_text_cache = {}
def render_white(text):
    if not text in _text_cache:
        surf = font.render(text ,True,(255,255,255))
        _text_cache[text] = surf
        return surf
    return _text_cache[text]


class Player(object):
    sprite=psprite
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)
        # indicates that we are standing on the ground
        # and thus are "allowed" to jump
        self.on_ground = True
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.jump_speed = 7
        self.move_speed = 3

    def update(self, move, blocks):

        # check if we can jump 
        if move.up and self.on_ground:
            self.yvel -= self.jump_speed

        # simple left/right movement
        if move.left:
                self.xvel = -self.move_speed
        if move.right:
                self.xvel = self.move_speed

        # if in the air, fall down
        if not self.on_ground:
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # but not too fast
            if self.yvel > max_gravity: self.yvel = max_gravity

        # if no left/right movement, x speed is 0, of course
        if not (move.left or move.right):
            self.xvel = 0

        # move horizontal, and check for horizontal collisions
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, blocks)

        # move vertically, and check for vertical collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.on_ground = False;
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, blocks)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, blocks):
        # all blocks that we collide with
        for block in [blocks[i] for i in self.rect.collidelistall(blocks)]:

            # if xvel is > 0, we know our right side bumped 
            # into the left side of a block etc.
            if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = block.rect.right

            # if yvel > 0, we are falling, so if a collision happpens 
            # we know we hit the ground (remember, we seperated checking for
            # horizontal and vertical collision, so if yvel != 0, xvel is 0)
            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                self.on_ground = True
                self.yvel = 0
            # if yvel < 0 and a collision occurs, we bumped our head
            # on a block above us
            if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")
while True:
        for block in blocklist:
            if any(block.rect.colliderect(b.rect) for b in blocklist if b is not block):
                blocklist.remove(block)

        if ingame==1:
            screen.fill(back_color)
            mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[K_a]:
                    anim+=1
                    if anim==9:
                            anim=1
            if key[K_d]:
                    anim+=1
                    if anim==9:
                            anim=1

            if key[K_LEFT]:
                try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.left+=32
                except:
                        pass
                try:
                        player.rect.left+=32
                except:
                        pass
            if key[K_RIGHT]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.left-=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.left-=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_UP]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.top+=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.top+=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_DOWN]:
                    try:
                        for b in blocklist:
                            b.rect.top-=32
                    except:
                            pass
                    try:
                        player.rect.top-=32
                    except:
                            pass
            if key[K_ESCAPE]:
                execfile('PiBlocks.pyw')
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    exit()
                if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == 4:
                        selected_block_index += 1
                    elif event.button == 5:
                        selected_block_index -= 1
                    selected_block_index = max(min(selected_block_index, num_of_types-1), 0)
                    selected_block_type = types[selected_block_index]
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key in key_map:
                        selected_block_type = key_map[event.key]
                        selected_block_index = types.index(selected_block_type)
                elif event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                    if key[K_LSHIFT]:
                        if not any(block.rect.collidepoint(mse) for block in blocklist):
                            snd=random.randint(1,3)
                            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                            if go==1:
                                if snd==1:
                                    place.play()
                                elif snd==2:
                                    place2.play()
                                elif snd==3:
                                    place3.play()
                                blocklist.append(Block(x,y,selected_block_type))
                    elif key[K_RSHIFT]:
                        to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                        for b in to_remove:
                                if go==1:
                                        blocklist.remove(b)
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if event.button == 1:
                        to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                        for b in to_remove:
                            if go==1:
                                    blocklist.remove(b)

                        if not to_remove:
                            snd=random.randint(1,3)
                            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                            if go==1:
                                    if snd==1:
                                        place.play()
                                    elif snd==2:
                                        place2.play()
                                    elif snd==3:
                                        place3.play()
                                    blocklist.append(Block(x,y,selected_block_type))

                    elif event.button == 3:
                        x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                        y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                        player=Player(x+16,y+16)

            move = Move(key[K_w], key[K_a], key[K_d])

            for b in blocklist:
                    if b.rect.left>=0:
                            if b.rect.right<=640:
                                    screen.blit(b.image, b.rect)

            if player:
                player.update(move, blocklist)
                if anim==1 or anim==2 or anim==3:
                        screen.blit(psprite, player.rect)
                elif anim==4 or anim==5 or anim==6:
                        screen.blit(psprite2, player.rect)
                elif anim==7 or anim==8 or anim==9:
                        screen.blit(psprite3, player.rect)
            x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
            y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
            screen.blit(curs,(x,y))
            clock.tick(60)
            screen.blit(render_white('PiBlocks Alpha 0.6'), (1,1))
            screen.blit(render_white('Selected Texture Pack: ' + texdir), (1,12))
            screen.blit(render_white('Selected Block: '+ selected_block_type.name), (1,25))
            if gotime==0:
                go=1
            else:
                gotime-=1
            pygame.display.update()
        elif ingame==0:
                blocklist=[]
                mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                player=[]
                key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                text=font.render(splash, True, (255,255,255))
                if key[K_RETURN]:
                        ingame=1
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            exit()
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                                print event.key
                if sbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                ingame='gen'
                                top=(random.randint(5,8)*32)
                                cen=(top+random.randint(4,6)*32)
                                down=15
                                across=0
                                blklvl=0
                                while across<640:
                                        while down>0:
                                                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                                                if blklvl==top:
                                                    blocklist.append(block_factory('grass', across, blklvl))
                                                if blklvl>top and blklvl<cen:
                                                        blocklist.append(block_factory('dirt', across, blklvl))
                                                if blklvl>cen-1:
                                                    blocklist.append(block_factory('stone', across, blklvl))
                                                down=down-1
                                                blklvl=blklvl+32

                                        if down==0:
                                                if across<1920:
                                                        per=(across/(32/5))
                                                        if per>100:
                                                                per=100
                                                        top=(random.randint(5,8)*32)
                                                        cen=(top+random.randint(4,6)*32)
                                                        down=15 
                                                        blklvl=0
                                                        across=across+32
                                                        down=15
                                                        drawgen=font.render('GENERATION:'+str(per)+'%%', True, (255,255,255))
                                                        screen.blit(drawgen,(1,1))
                                                        pygame.display.flip()
                                        go=0
                                        ingame=1

                if qbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                exit()
                if tbtnrect.collidepoint(mse):
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                                ingame='texsel'
                screen.blit(backimg,(0,0))
                screen.blit(text,(364,76))
                screen.blit(sbtn,sbtnrect)
                screen.blit(qbtn,qbtnrect)
                screen.blit(tbtn,tbtnrect)
                pygame.display.flip()
        elif ingame=='texsel':
                 screen.blit(clsimg,(0,0))
                 inp = ask(screen, 'Texture Directory')
                 f=open('texdir.txt','w')
                 f.write(str(inp))
                 f.close()
                 pygame.display.flip()
                 execfile('PiBlocks.pyw')
```

and the config file (`settings.cfg`):

```
[Options]
Backcolor: (100, 100, 100)
TextureDir: .
DefaultBlock: dirt
ScreenSize: (640, 480)
Caption: PiBlocks | By Sam Tubb
Splash: ('Some splash!', 'Play This!', 'Whhooooaaaa!!')
```

Further steps are fixing indentation, clean up the deep nesting of `if` blocks, maybe  introduce classes that represent the different game states, and removing the evil empty try/except blocks. Also, some code of blocks could also extrated to functions to improve readability.